# My git doesn't track anything "git commit-m "something"

Tags: reactjs, macos, terminal, iterm2, iterm

When I try to add something on github it gets stuck at "git commit -m"", it gives me multiple errors, and when I also was trying to push to origin master, writer object was loading for so long and in the end it was giving me error about the space which I cleared it.

The code is from my terminal

```
folders/sicKicks_files/0.ba7ac18bf309342a7f93.hot-update.js
    deleted:    ../all the folders/sicKicks_files/ad_status.js
    deleted:    ../all the folders/sicKicks_files/bKOTKHtbM54.html
    deleted:    ../all the folders/sicKicks_files/base.js
    deleted:    ../all the folders/sicKicks_files/bundle.js
    deleted:    ../all the folders/sicKicks_files/default-user-profile-picture-6.png
    deleted:    ../all the folders/sicKicks_files/dfD9zXZWxFiDhYhWq7JGeIab03YqAOfkkE7CNMbfLXw.js
    deleted:    ../all the folders/sicKicks_files/remote.js
    deleted:    ../all the folders/sicKicks_files/www-embed-player.js
    deleted:    ../all the folders/sicKicks_files/www-player-webp-vfltH5uc5.css
    deleted:    ../all the folders/work-on-portofilo
    modified:   ../folders/zeugma-spa (untracked content)
    modified:   ../instabot.py (modified content)
    modified:   ../javascript-practices (modified content)

Untracked files:
    ../iTerm 2.app/
    ../iTerm2-3_2_9.zip

no changes added to commit
➜  counter-app git:(counter-app) ✗
```

Comment: `git commit -m` doesn't even connect to github, it's a purely local command.

Comment: it was connected to github before, I didn't had any problems with it

Comment: have you tried `git commit -n -m [commit message]` ??

Comment: now I can't do 'git push origin master' , I'm getting this ```fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.``` I've been trying to connect my github or if that's the problem, couldn't figure out